# Why wasn't Iran colonized by any country?

Tags: united-kingdom, iran

Why wasn't Iran colonized by any country, especially by British empire?

Comment: Persia/Iran was colonized by the Rashidun Caliphate in7th century.

Comment: @Alex I'd not call the Rashidun invasion colonization. It wasn't followed by a stream of Arab settlers as it did in Levant. Iraq already had Arab tribes who were vassals of Persian Empire. The first commander on Iranian front, Musna bin Haritha on Iranian front was himself from Iraqi province of Persia. The only former territories of Persian Empire that saw influx of Arab settlers were Arab provinces of the Empire.

Comment: @OP, I'd say there are various reasons. In times of Safavid dynasty, Persia was a valuable ally of European powers against the Ottomans. Later, One of the greatest colonizing power and enemies of the British, the French were very close allies of Iran, as they wanted to use it as transit to take the British head-on in India. Plus Iran was an ancient and civilized country, not some place with few hunters and gatherers. They could be overwhelmed, but sooner or later, they were bound to break free. Which is why no lands in Asia or North Africa were colonized like America or SA.

Comment: Why wasn't Greece colonised by any country?

Comment: @OrangeDog, if you are talking about ancient Greece, then the answer is the history of colonialism started in the 15th century.  If you are talking about modern Greece, the answer is, Greece was part of modern Europe.

Comment: @anonymous it wasn't a question to be answered, but to highlight the assumptions in the question: why should Iran (or indeed any country that wasn't) have been colonised, particularly by the British empire?

Comment: @OrangeDog, Coz, Iran was in the ME, and Britain colonized most of the ME and Africa.

Comment: @anonymous Turkey then

Comment: @OrangeDog, Turkey itself had colonies.

Comment: @anonymous yes I know, why are you answering these questions?

Comment: By the way, this discussion misses that Persia was invaded and conquered and colonized by Alexander:-)

Comment: Probably because Iran has nothing that anyone else wants. The whole Middle East would be completely ignorable if they didn't have oil - and recent developments (e.g. North American shale oil) have reduced the importance of the Middle East's oil deposits. I remember flying into Istanbul back in the 1970's, looking down at the brown burned-up landscape - not a sign of anything green or growing - and thinking, "And people have been fighting over this chunk of dirt for *centuries*? ***WHY***???".

Comment: @anonymous: Re "the history of colonialism started in the 15th century", this is flat-out wrong.  For one instance of many, ncient Greece founded colonies all around the Mediterranean & Black Seas.

Comment: @BobJarvis For Istanbul specifically, it's incredibly important strategically, due to controlling both the land route between the Middle East/Africa/Asia and Europe and also the sea route from the Black to the Mediterranean (and, thus, the rest of the world.) This was perhaps more important in past centuries than it is today, though. Even today, though, controlling the Bosphorus in Istanbul means controlling access to major Russian sea ports.

Comment: @Alex, that doesn't conform to the definition of colonialism.

Comment: @reirab: I'm actually aware of this. But my 17-year-old self was amazed that people would fight, and die, over a rather unattractive piece of dirt in a climate that I, personally, didn't find all that enjoyable.

Comment: @Alex Are you kidding me?! You think a bunch of barbarian Arab people colonized Sassanid Empire at its apex point, when pretty much the whole land of Byzantine Empire was conquered by Sassanid Imperial Army? That's ridiculous to say Rashidun Caliphate (A bunch of jerks in fact!) colonized Persian Empire.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Persia / Iran was sovereign for most of its history.

[Actually](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran#Early_modern_period), Persia / Iran *had* colonies, mostly in the Caucasus region, before they were [lost to Russia in the early 1800's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Persian_Wars).

At times Russia and / or Britain held some Iranian territory occupied, but Iran was not "defeated" wholesale prior to the [Anglo-Soviet invasion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Soviet_invasion_of_Iran) in 1941... by which time "colonization" was no longer on the British agenda, and Soviet forces withdrew in 1946.

Comment: It must be noted that even the ww2 invasion was aimed to secure supply lines for Soviet troops fighting the Germans in Caucasus, Ukraine and broadly the whole Eastern front. It wasn't an effort aimed at colonizing Iran.

Comment: What about Soviet forces staying in Iranian Azerbaijan after the war was finished?

Comment: @RezaRezazadegan: There's some difference between occupied / annexed territory, and holding a *colony*.

Answer (score 10):

Iran was defeated in his history before the age of colonization:

- By Muslims, in 633 A.D. It lasted more than two centuries and even led to the change of the countries religion. The Persian Empire's official religion was Zoroastrianism.  [[Source]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_conquest_of_Persia)
- By Mongols, in 1219 A.D.[[Source]](https://sites.google.com/site/afireinasia/home/introduction/conquest-of-persia-1)

According to the definition, "colonization is a process by which a central system of power dominates the surrounding land and its components."

So we come to the conclusion that Iran was colonized and that's why more than half of the Persian words are from Arabic origin. There are also many words of Turkish origin entered into Persian by Mongol invasion(whose language belongs to the Turkish family of languages). So I do not agree with you, Iran was for many years colonized.

Comment: How much rent did these empires extract out of their colony tho? I mean was Persia as productive a colony (in terms of forced rent transfer to the metropol) as Mexico or Peru were for Spain or the Congo for Belgium? Does it even compare?

Comment: Weal, we know the answers to quiet a lot of these questions (if not exactly, at least in the ballparks) for the roman colonization of northern Africa and the Levant for example (so your point about the period in which these events were happening is a bit moot)

Comment: Sure, [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-was-North-Africa-considered-the-breadbasket-of-the-Roman-Empire-considering-how-infertile-it-is-Was-it-just-because-of-Egypt) are people talking about the size of the transfers from roman colony of northern africa and the levant to rome. My point is such transfers between rome and its colonies were sizeable. And that was before the 7th century. So clearly the idea of drawning resources from the colony was not invented in 19th century europe.

Comment: saddly no, I do not know much about Iran. I think that your answer adds something important to the top ranked answer (Persia *was* colonized multiple times). I think it would improve your answer to include that these colonization were less predatory in nature. The reason of why that might have been so (maybe Persia had less easily transferable loot?) is of interest to the question (the *Why* in the OP's title)

Comment: I'm native Iranian and your claim of "half of the Persian words are from Arabic origin" is COMPLETELY INCORRECT! I would say less than 5% percent of words in our modern Persian language "MAYBE" their root could be traced to Arabic language.

Comment: _Salam dust-e aziz_ . This phrase is considerd a moderne persian phrase  and all of its three words are arabic. Besides the fact that you are iranian does not mean that you can distinguish the origine of words. I mentioned that because I have a MA degree  in ancient persian languages.

Answer (score 2):

Let me address the issue of colonization in 19th century, "especially by British"  **and Russian** empires.

A short answer is *because the [Great Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Game) was essentially a draw*, with the two sides (British and Russian empires) settling on having spheres of influence (in Iran). The story (British-Russian competition over Iran and the eventual settlement) is discussed at the end of Chapter 1 in

Elena Andreeva, ``Russia and Iran in the Great Game: Travelogues and Orientalism.''   Routledge, Abington, England. 2007.

To quote her book:

> **Formally, Iran was never a colony, mainly because of the rivalry between Russia and Britain – the balance of power between Russia and Britain was of particular importance in preserving the integrity of Iran.** However, with the passage of time, Iran’s sovereignty was growing more and more limited....
>
> Britain was mainly concerned with preserving the formal independence and integrity of Persia in order to defend the Indian empire. Russia, as mentioned above, deprived Iran of her Transcaucasian territories in the first half of the nineteenth century and of territory in the northeast in the second half of the century, and she had further expansionist designs on northern and northeastern Iran. Both Britain and Russia were striving to exercise as much influence
>   as possible on the Qajar rulers in order to gain support for their actions
>   in Iran and to repel their rivals. In the second half of the nineteenth
>   century, the political, diplomatic and military activities of Russia and
>   Britain in Iran came to be combined with their competition for concessions and loans
>
> The tug-of-war between Russia and Britain for concessions led to the
>   increasing economic encroachment of the two empires on Iran, hampering a balanced development of its economy. One striking example was the blocking of railroad construction in Iran at the end of the nineteenth century due to the attempts by Russia and Britain to prevent each other from receiving the railroad concession.  The Shah’s pledge not to allow foreign companies to build railroads without consulting Russia lasted until the early twentieth century...
>
> The most extraordinary and humiliating event in Iran’s relations with
>   Russia and Britain took place on 31 August 1907. That was the date of
>   the signing of the Anglo-Russian Convention, which divided Iran into
>   spheres of influence and reconciled the differences between the governments of Russia and Britain. Though the preamble to the agreement mentioned the integrity and independence of Persia, the Iranian Government was not even informed about the Convention. According to the terms of the Convention, the northern and central areas of Iran were reserved for Russia, with Britain promising “not to seek for herself, and not to support in favor of British subjects, or in favor of the subjects of third Powers, any concession of a political or commercial nature.”
>   Britain also promised “not to oppose directly or indirectly, demands for
>   similar Concessions in this region which are supported by the Russian
>   Government.” Southeastern Iran came under the British sphere of
>   influence, where Russia undertook similar obligations. The area between
>   the Russian and British spheres was made neutral territory...

I refer to the book for further details.